# Specific replacement of quotes in a string object

Tags: javascript, string, object, double-quotes

I've an object as a string, like this :

```
{'fze': 'ffefe', 'zfe': 'grg', 'fefe': 'gggv', "c'est": 'aaze', "it's": "jack's time", 'hey': 'now'}
```

I'd like to replace all single quote to double quote, but not the one that is inside the double quote (for example, the words : "c'est", "it's" and "jack's time", because they already have a single quote inside)

The final result would be this :

```
{"fze": "ffefe", "zfe": "grg", "fefe": "gggv", "c'est": "aaze", "it's": "jack's time", "hey": "now"}
```

I already tried with `replaceAll`, but I need more conditions for that.

Do you have an ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried - also read our [ask] page for more tips on how to improve this question - Welcome to StackOverflow, btw!

Comment: If you want a string in the end you could use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). If you want to keep it as an object I can not really see the relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your input is really a string, a combination of `eval` + `JSON.stringify` should do the trick:

```js
your_string = `{'fze': 'ffefe', 'zfe': 'grg', 'fefe': 'gggv', "c'est": 'aaze', "it's": "jack's time", 'hey': 'now'}`

console.log(JSON.stringify(eval('0,' + your_string)))
```

As usual with `eval`, never use it with untrusted input.

The `0,` part is necessary to turn the input into an expression, otherwise `eval` would treat it as a code block (and fail).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you. I don't usually use the eval function, I didn't know that it could solve this issue. But why did you put a '0, ' string inside the function ?

Comment: @vinsouz78: added an explanation